# How to shrink a Tempdb without restart the server

Tags: sql-server

I want  to shrink my tempdb without restart. I tried all possibilities available in Internet like
1opentransaction(there is no open transaction)
2.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? https://am2.co/2020/04/stop-trying-to-shrink-tempdb/

Comment: I have never been able to get tempdb to shrink much after something causes it to grow unexpectedly--you'll just have to wait until you can restart SQL Server.  One thing to note, if you get a tempdb file to shrink even a little bit, that will be the new size, so you need reset the file sizes to make sure they are created at the size you want.  https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/re-size-tempdb-files

Answer (score 0):

Before you try to shrink your tempdb could be good a practice:

1. Validate how is doing the Virtual Logs Files on your Tempdb.
2. Check the server contention
3. Use sp_whoisactive to check the tempdb allocations and who is using it.

My advice to shrink your Tempdb is set the Initial Data File sizes to a size that your baseline recommends is good for your environment, set the growth using exact values like 4000MB instead of percentage, then when you have a maintenance window do a restart of the SQL Server Services to apply the new sizes and shrink your tempdb.

Perhaps, if wait to the next maintenance windows is not a possibility, you can run this code to shrink your tempdb [Pasted below]. 
I have to do this a couple of times in PROD servers, you need to be careful in what time you perform this because you can affect your production applications.

**WARNING** My recommendation is run it during a time when your server has fewer transactions

[ShrinkTempDB size and VLF Script](https://gist.github.com/jmontero19/11ccf089c6ee2efcfda4a7dbe19f6fde)

Comment: Hi @Jmonterohn, I have mentioned already as so far in points wise. Currently, I don't want to restart my machine, because this is prod server. Total allocation of this dB is 900gb. Tempdb shown full even though it has 99% free space.

Comment: H @srinivasa p  Running the script that I have pasted above, you should able to shrink your tempdb without restart your SQL Server instance

Comment: Hi @Jmonterohn , I have already tried which was given the script. I haven't face any issue on tempdb logfile. Because, it's been shrink to less size(5mb). My concern is to shrink data file with out restart sql machine.

Comment: Regarding your concern, I will advise you on the following. A good practice that you can do for it is checked if the tempdb has large tables or objects that were not dropped. You can check what are the objects consuming space in the TempDB. Right-click on the TempDB-> go to Reports-> Standard Reports-> Disk Usage by Top Tables. Validate if these objects are no longer needed then dropped the objects and finally to release the unused space runs: DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(TempDB, ‘%free_space’); GO DBCC SHRINKFILE(tempdev,0). Doing it you'll release space & shrink your tempdb datafile without restart

Comment: I have checked the temp table objects but all are showing less size and user object as well. My data file is showing 99 percent free.

Comment: DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(TempDB, ‘%free_desire_space’); GO                        DBCC SHRINKFILE(tempdev,0) GO

Comment: It does not work.